# Need CSS text color for a:hover to take precedence over a:visited

Tags: css

I have some css code that shows a background color on hover. The text is white on a blue background.

Otherwise, if there is no hover, the text is blue with a white background.
However, when the link has been visited, the text remains blue with a blue background on hover.

How can I force the hover text color to take precedence?

```
a:link{
    color:#3399cc;
}

a:hover{
    background-color:#3399cc;
    color:#ffffff;
}
a:visited{
    color:#3399cc;
}
a:active{
    color:#3399cc;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think specifying the style data for `:hover` *after* the style data for `:visited` is enough to do the trick:

```
a:visited{  
    color:#3399cc;  
}  
a:hover{  
    background-color:#3399cc;  
    color:#ffffff;  
}
```

Comment: There are several acronyms to remember the proper order for link properties - one is LoVe HAte - Link; Visited; Hover; Active

Answer (score 6):

See *Eric Meyer's* article on the subject: [Ordering The Link States](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/06/04/ordering-the-link-states/)

It is suggested, that you use the “link-visited-hover-active” **LVHA-rule**, referring to the order of the pseudo-classes among the CSS rules. The comments bring up some easily recognizable acronyms on the ordering (adding `:focus` into the pack):

- **L**ord **V**ader's **F**ormer **H**andle, **A**nakin
- **L**ord **V**ader **F**roze **H**ans **A**ss

Answer (score 4):

if I'm not mistaken, all you have to do is switch the order, put the :hover class after the :visted class in your style sheet

Answer (score 3):

LoVeHAte = link,visited,hover,active

Answer (score -1):

One method would be to use the `!important` keyword:

```
a:visited
{
    color:#3399cc;
}
a:hover
{
    background-color: #3399cc;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

That will make sure that the `:hover` takes precedence.

It might also work to replace your `a:visited hover`, which means a `<hover>` element (doesn't exist!), with `a:visited:hover`.

As already mentioned, changing the order of the styles sshould be a sufficient fix: later definitions take precedence over earlier ones.

Comment: please no !important hack. There is always a valid way around such a thing.